# How to get the real path of a sh file that is being sourced

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, paths, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I added this line into my `~/.bashrc`

```
. /mnt/c/Users/enzo/drive/projects/dotfiles/init.sh
```

And and inside of init.sh I am trying to get the path of `init.sh` but I am not able to.

I tried this so far:

```
CURDIR=`/bin/pwd`
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
ABSPATH=$(readlink -f $0)
ABSDIR=$(dirname $ABSPATH)
REAL=$(realpath $0)

echo "CURDIR is $CURDIR"
echo "BASEDIR is $BASEDIR"
echo "ABSPATH is $ABSPATH"
echo "ABSDIR is $ABSDIR"
echo "REAL is $REAL"
```

Output:

```
CURDIR is /mnt/c/Users/enzo
BASEDIR is /bin
ABSPATH is /bin/bash
ABSDIR is /bin
REAL is /bin/bash
```

I'm under windows subsystem for linux.

Comment: I just need this path `/mnt/c/Users/enzo/drive/projects/dotfiles/` to make the script working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `BASH_SOURCE` instead of `$0`:

```
realpath ${BASH_SOURCE}
```

in your script:

```
REAL=$(realpath ${BASH_SOURCE})
```

Answer (score 6):

When you *source* a Bash script, `$0` will not hold the name of your sourced script, but of the Bash executable.

You should read the value of `$BASH_SOURCE` instead, so that the absolute path to the directory of your script would be

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$(realpath "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")")"
```

Related: [choosing between $0 and BASH_SOURCE (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006505/4464570)